# Hang a plant pot to a concrete ceiling

Tags: concrete, ceiling

Having fixed quite a few things to walls in my life, I am about to hang something for the first time to a ceiling. It will be a plant pot weighing below 5 kg. The ceiling is made from concrete. I have always used plastic anchors to fix things to concrete and brick walls. But I am not sure that's sufficiently strong for a vertical hole in a ceiling. Besides I have read somewhere that plastic anchors will melt in case of fire, so they shouldn't be used in ceilings to fix anything that can hurt humans. Not that I expect people to enjoy the shadow of my plants in the event of fire. And the pots will be in the corner of a room, not above the escape path. Still I want it done properly. A sleeve anchor looks like an overkill for such weight. Suprisingly I couldn't find any simple reliable (standard?) recommendations on this topic. Are there any?

FWIW so far I've bought d4.5x40 mm thread hooks looking roughly like this: http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1kp_RMXXXXXc5XXXXq6xXFXXXX/8-3-8mm-65mm-16mm-Metal-font-b-Hooks-b-font-font-b-Screws-b-font.jpg